# Switch selenium form 2.53.1 to 3.x

Tags: selenium3

My project uses selenium 2.53.1 and I want to upgrade to 3.x.

I update de dependencies on my build.gradle file, but now, I can't import some libraries needed for the project:

- DesiredCapabilities
- Actions

Where are them now? Do I need extra dependencies?

My current dependencies:

> compile("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.4.0")
>      compile("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-server:3.4.0")
>      compile("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:3.4.0")
>      compile("org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-api:3.4.0")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, was an IDE error. There were loading two versions of selenium at the same time.